# Page number position even more outside type area

Tags: page-numbering

I wonder how I can move the page number even more to the outside:

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|    dsad sadsad sad s       |
|    dasdsa dasd sadas       |
|    dasd sadas ds asd       |
|                            |
|    dsad sadsad sad s       |
|    dasdsa dasd sadas       |
|    dasd sadas ds asd       |
|                            |
|    dsad sadsad sad s       |
|    dasdsa dasd sadas       |
|    dasd sadas ds asd       |
|                            |
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
```

If possible I would like to alter the position up/down as well.
The page numbers need to be at a specific location on the page, since I have to use pre-made background images which have empty spaces where the page numbers should appear.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, sectionprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
\ofoot*{\Huge{~\pagemark}}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.5cm,margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\blindmathpaper
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the `ifoddpage` package to have the page number in the outer margin:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt, sectionprefix]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \usepackage{ifoddpage}
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
    \setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
    \setkomafont{pagination}{}
    \setlength{\footskip}{20pt}%
    \ofoot*{\Huge\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\rlap{\quad\pagemark}\else\llap{\pagemark\quad}\fi}
    \setlength{\footskip}{20pt}%

    \usepackage[bindingoffset=0.5cm,margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}

    \blindtext[5]
    \blindmathpaper
    \blindmathpaper

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```latex
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=\textwidth+3em:0pt}
```

after the geometry settings to enlarge the foot width by `3em` in the outer margin.

There is a warning by `scrlayer-scrpage`: you should enlarge  `\footheight` to at least 19.16791pt. This can be done by the class option `footheight=19.16791pt`. The foot skip can be changed by the `geometry` option `footskip`.

```latex
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,% default
  10pt, 
  %sectionprefix,% unknown/unused option
  footheight=19.16791pt% <- added as suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.5cm,margin=1.8cm,
  footskip=20pt%<- changed, use the geometry option
]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AtBeginDocument{\KOMAoptions{footwidth=\textwidth+3em:0pt}}%<-added, use after geometry settings
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagination}{\Huge}% <-changed
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed

\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\blindmathpaper
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the vertial position of the footer, you can use

```latex
%\providecommand*\Ifstrstart{\ifstrstart}%needed for older KOMA-Script versions
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot.}{\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=15pt]{#1}}{}%
}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot.}{\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=15pt]{#1}}{}%
}
```

But you could also declare new layers for the page number.